# Using hidden property from SuperClass to Subclass

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I would like to inherit properties like hidden, appends, date from superclass to its subclass, where Sup class can define its own properties without override their parent.

Something like this,

```
class SuperClass extends Model
{
    protected $hidden = ['pivot','deleted_at'];
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass
{
    protected $hidden = ['password'];
}
```

So, the hidden property of SubClass would have all three properties.
Any idea?

Comment: do it in the constructor

Comment: No because you are overwriting property in subclass

Comment: Thanks, I thought Laravel had handle this, so may be I expect something too magical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all property in subclass then you can do it using constructor:

```
class SuperClass extends Eloquent
{
    protected $hidden = ['pivot','deleted_at'];
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->hidden[]='password';
    }
    public function get_hidden()
    {
        return $this->hidden;
    }
}
$obj = new SubClass();
var_dump($obj->get_hidden());
```

Comment: Don't forget to call the parent constructor.

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks but Superclass doesn't have constructor in demo that's why I haven't do it

Comment: Eloquent does though (although to be fair it's meant to be called `Model`)

Comment: Yes, It's meant to be Model instead of Eloquent. Anyway thanks for answer this stupid question :D